how to invoke python virtual environment from script
Context: MacOS Ventura 13.6.7
A Python virtual environment successful invokes from the command terminal:
source my3211/bin/activate

My pyActivate.sh script:
echo "source my3211/bin/activate"
source my3211/bin/activate

Is invoked by:
./pyActivate.sh

The virtual environment is fails to  invoke. Why the failure and what is the corrective action?

The issue is that when you call another program which is what  your script is that call creates a new shell and then imports the venv into that and then it returns to the original shell.
You need to source your new script so that it chnages the environment of the current shell.
e.g.
source ./pyActivate.sh

Another way is if using zsh to make your pyactivatye a function.
